# Implementation of Lazy<T> for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, generics, lazy-loading

.NET 4.0 has a nice utility class called [System.Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) that does lazy object initialization. I would like to use this class for a 3.5 project. One time I saw an implementation somewhere in a stackoverflow answer but I can't find it anymore. Does someone have an alternative implementation of Lazy? It doesn't need all the thread safety features of the framework 4.0 version.

**Updated:**

Answers contain a non thread safe and a thread safe version.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is an implementation that I use.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides support for lazy initialization.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Specifies the type of object that is being lazily initialized.</typeparam>
public sealed class Lazy<T>
{
    private readonly object padlock = new object();
    private readonly Func<T> createValue;
    private bool isValueCreated;
    private T value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the lazily initialized value of the current Lazy{T} instance.
    /// </summary>
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isValueCreated)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (!isValueCreated)
                    {
                        value = createValue();
                        isValueCreated = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether a value has been created for this Lazy{T} instance.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                return isValueCreated;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Lazy{T} class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createValue">The delegate that produces the value when it is needed.</param>
    public Lazy(Func<T> createValue)
    {
        if (createValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("createValue");

        this.createValue = createValue;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and returns a string representation of the Lazy{T}.Value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The string representation of the Lazy{T}.Value property.</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems I have with this: First of all, it's preferable to `lock` a private object than to `lock (this)`, since you can't control who else might lock on your `Lazy` instance.  Second, I don't think making `isValueCreated` a `volatile` field serves any purpose when you're already using a critical section (does it?  Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I agree volatile is used when locking is not used. From MSDN: The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access. Using the volatile modifier ensures that one thread retrieves the most up-to-date value written by another thread.

Comment: @Aaronaught, @BC - I know this may sound stupid but imagine a situation where `isValueCreated` is read and written nearly at the same time. If  `isValueCreated` is `volatile` then the extra lock will not need to be taken because the latest value was read. One simple lock may not seem like much but I did it for completeness sake. As for the `this` lock, I do see your point but it just never was an issue I ran into while using this class.

Comment: The code doesn't seems to be entirely thread-safe yet. It may be better to use a memory barrier as suggested in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_.NET_.28Visual_Basic.2C_C.23.29

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need thread-safety, it's pretty easy to put one together with a factory method.  I use one very similar to the following:

```
public class Lazy<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> initializer;
    private bool isValueCreated;
    private T value;

    public Lazy(Func<T> initializer)
    {
        if (initializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initializer");
        this.initializer = initializer;
    }

    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get { return isValueCreated; }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isValueCreated)
            {
                value = initializer();
                isValueCreated = true;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone who might copy this: It can be easy to have closure confusion with the initializer here. Make sure to capture your values!

Comment: @Rex: Do you mean, if you're initializing the `Lazy<T>` instance from a loop?  Does `System.Lazy` do some magic to sidestep the normal dangers of capturing?

Comment: a loop is a good example. I doubt if the real `Lazy` is any different, though I am not sure. Just thought I'd point it out because I see a lot of people get themselves in trouble with this kind of pattern.

Comment: @Rex: Alrighty, just wanted to make sure you were referring to a usage scenario and not a design flaw that I failed to recognize.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat simplify version of aaron's

```
public class Lazy<T> where T : new()
{ 
  private T value; 

  public bool IsValueCreated { get; private set;}

  public T Value 
  { 
    get 
    { 
        if (!IsValueCreated) 
        { 
            value = new T();
            IsValueCreated = true; 
        } 
        return value; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: @BC : Yes, which is what the ` where T : new() ` means.

Answer (score -1):

Some funny (but not very usable) stuff can be added: implicit coversion from delegate:

```
public static implicit operator Lazy<T>(Func<T> initializer)
{
    return new Lazy<T>(initializer);
}
```

And usage

```
private static Lazy<int> Value = new Func<int>(() => 24 * 22);
```

C# compiler have some problem with performing this conversion, for example assigning lambda expression does not work, but it is one more thing causes your colleguas to think a bit :)

Comment: lambdas can either be expression trees or delegates so the compiler refuse to consider them to be one or the other. same reason why you can't put a lambda in a var. Really annoying sometimes...

Comment: You are right, but this code does not work even with methods:
`
public static int NewValue()
        {
            return 24 * 15;
        }
public static Lazy<int> V = NewValue; // Compilation Error, needs new Func<int>(NewValue)`